# Wordpress Deprecated: define(): Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, undefined

I'm having the following problem, but I'm not able to figure out how to solve it, I also tried to comment on the define but it doesn't solve the problem.

Error:

```
Deprecated: define(): Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated in /storage/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/themehunk-customizer/featuredlite/inc/constant.php on line 3

Deprecated: define(): Declaration of case-insensitive constants is deprecated in /storage/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/themehunk-customizer/featuredlite/inc/constant.php on line 4
```

My doubt could be versions problems from the one used by wordpress and the hosting where the site is loaded?

Comment: What is the version of the plugin?

Comment: No plugin, wordpress.

Comment: Can you post the code of lines that's causing error?

Comment: Please also mention your PHP version.

Comment: @Paul But the error is showing in your themehunk-customizer plugin. Can you tell me the version of themehunk customizer plugin ?

Comment: It is a problem with a plugin and if it hasn't been updated to support PHP 7.3 you'll need to contact the plugin's author and ask that it be updated/fixed.

Comment: For the moment I solved by false setting the constant, WP_DEBUG which was set to true, Thanks anyway, as soon as I have more time I will investigate and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that the "WP_DEBUG" entry in the "wp-config" file is "false".

Comment: You're right, for the moment I solved by doing this the way you indicated.

Comment: Setting `WP_DEBUG` to _false_ will hide the error; it does not actually address the challenge. More detail about the depreciation notice at [php.net](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/case_insensitive_constant_deprecation).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7.3: Deprecate calling define() with third parameter true
[see here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/case_insensitive_constant_deprecation)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using PHP 7.3 And Defining case-insensitive constants is deprecated as of PHP 7.3.0.

I don't see any workaround on this but you can downgrade your PHP to 7.2 to make it work.

Comment: I'm doing tests, but I don't know what the problem could be.